# String.chars() - why "i - '0'" is used here?

Tags: java, java-stream

I resolved task on codewars, which looks like this:

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num
>   and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of
>   times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single
>   digit.
>
> For example:

```
 persistence(39) == 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                      // and 4 has only one digit

 persistence(999) == 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                       // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2

 persistence(4) == 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

After solving this I found other resolution:

```
  class Persist {
    public static int persistence(long n) {
        int times = 0;
        while (n >= 10) {
            n = Long.toString(n).chars().reduce(1, (r, i) -> r * (i - '0'));
            times++;
        }
        return times;
    }
 }
```

It is working, but why we have to do: - '0' in reduce?

Comment: To get the actual integer value. If not, you get the ASCII equivalent for that character. Ex: ASCII of 0 char is `48`. So if you reduce that from 0 char you get ‘0`

Comment: The hack works because all the digit characters are assigned consecutive code values, from '0'==48, '1'==49, and so on up to '9'==57.

Comment: You don't need the string conversion at all, and consequently don't need the `- '0'`. You can simply extract the last digit using `% 10`, divide by 10, and keep going until your number is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i - '0'` is a common hack to convert an ASCII (or similar) digit's value into an actual number. For example, the encoding of `'5'` isn't actually `5` but some other value (53 or something in ASCII, I think). But the encoding of `'5'` is 5 larger than the encoding of `'0'` in most systems. So subtracting the value of `'0'` (the encoding for character '0') from the encoding of character '5' will yield a *numerical value* of 5.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is a way to convert `char` (or like in your case `int` which holds codepoint) representing digit (like `char ch = '3';`) into `int` which will hold number corresponding to that digit (here `int num = 3;`).

---

Variable of type `char` doesn't actually hold *graphical representation* of a character, but it holds *number* corresponding to *position/index* of that character in Unicode Table. For instance small letter [`"a"`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0061/) is placed at index 97 and that is the value `char ch = 'a';` would hold in its 16-bytes (since that is the size of `char` type).

Since **`char` contains a *number*** we are allowed to use operators which work on numbers like `+` and `-`. This means we can write code like `'b' - 'a'` which will be executed as `97 - 96` and result in integer `1`. We can also use `int - char` or `char - int` because both of those forms will be converted to `int - int` (`char` will be converted to `int`) and return `int` which represents **DISTANCE between those characters**.

#### And that is main idea behind `i - '0'`.

We know that in Unicode Table digits are placed *somewhere* (we don't deed to know where exactly) in order ... 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .... (and there are no characters between them).

This gives us certainty that

- `'9' - '9'` would return 0,
- `'9' - '8'` would return 1,
- `'9' - '7'` would return 2,
- ...
- `'9' - '0'` would return 9,
- `'8' - '0'` would return 8,
- `'7' - '0'` would return 7,
- ...
- `'1' - '0'` would return 1,
- `'0' - '0'` would return 0.

So in short `indexOfNumberN - indexOfZero` gives us `int` with value of `NumberN`.

---

To avoid such confusing code you can rewrite lambda to more readable form

`(r, i) -> r * Character.getNumericValue(i)`